# ASP .Net Razor: format substract of 2 DateTime to a string specific format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got 1 model.DateTime value (which is I'm getting from Database) and I want to represent model DateTime which is end time, and DateTime.Now as now time.

I want to format subtract of that 2 DateTime-s as a specific String format "**dd:hh:mm:ss**".

Comment: A `<label>` element does not seem appropriate here. You can use `@item.duration.ToString("dd:hh:mm:ss")` or use a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd:hh:mm:ss}")]` attribute applied to your property and `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.duration)` But that will only work if your property is `DateTime`

Comment: Yeah it is DateTime, but there's problem I've set up as label because I'm sending server push notifications and I'm getting label and changing it's content. That's why I'd like to use label somehow with this format if it's possible ofcourse.

Comment: A `<label>` is an element associated with a form control (clicing on it sets focus to the associated control) so using it is not correct. But you can always use `<label>@item.duration.ToString("dd:hh:mm:ss")</label>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke seems it's not working: when i write that part of code you provided in comment, i see as output on screen only: dd:hh:mm:ss ?! It prints only format not formated duration

Comment: It works fine. What is the initial value of `item.duration`?

Comment: I am reading 4 rows from database and displaying, each has ~10 000 value. (i've set long to represent duration in seconds)

Comment: I said previously that it works if your property is `DateTime` (and you confirmed it was) - but now your saying its not! You need to your property to be `DateTime` (you cannot format a number to a date)

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad, I have 2 fields in my database one is DateTime closeTime, and one is long duration, i need to do closeTime - DateTime.Now and to use this format method. Is it possible on View to do this operation and to show it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116332/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-luka032).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ASP .Net view page you can open razor block and you can calculate difference between 2 variables that are DateTime type.

```
@{
    DateTime end = (DateTime)item.close_date_time;                               
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan diff = end.Subtract(now);
}
```

Then you can simply convert TimeSpan diff to string:

```
@diff.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss")
```

And by that I've solved time difference and to format it to specific string.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Simply you can do this:

```
DateTime CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
item.duration.Subtract(CurrentDateTime).ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Suggest you edit this to show the format string necessary for a `TimeSpan` as per the edited answer (i.e. `.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss")`) And the 2nd part of the answer is irrelevant since its not `string`. As it stands, this answer is wrong and will be down voted

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thanks for your attention, but answer is accepted.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke post what you think is a correct answer!

Comment: There is no point, just update your answer so that its now correct :)